# Click in ipython terminal window genrate MouseEvenType.MOUSE_DOWN exception

Tags: python, exception, ipython

On Windows 10, I'm running ipython 7.13.0. When I click in the window where the ipython prompt is shown, I'm getting an exception thrown that says

```
Exception 'MouseEventType.MOUSE_DOWN' is not a valid MouseEventType
```

I then need to press enter multiple times to get the prompt back. It seems to behave normally in all other ways. I'm using Anaconda as a package manager, regularly updating it using conda so I don't know when this broke other than I've been seeing this for several weeks.

I've done some searching for this error but haven't seen it reported. Any ideas on what is broken?

Answer (score 2):

I found this link that helped: https://copdips.com/2020/04/fixing-ipython-on-Windows10-ConEmu-mouse-event-bug.html.

But basically you have to update `prompt_toolkit` to version 3.0.5 (or higher). I was on 3.0.4.
To update, run this:

```
pip install prompt_toolkit==3.0.5
```